# find convergent subnet

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I`m trying to learn how to use nets and subnets to prove some theorems. I came across this problem in Banach space book: 
let K be a compact subset of a topological space X. suppose that $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$ is a net in X such that whenever U is open set that includes K and $\alpha\in I$ , there is a $\beta_{\alpha,U}$ in I such that $\alpha \preceq \beta_{\alpha,U}$ and $x_{\beta_{\alpha,U}} \in U$. prove that some subnet of $(x_{\alpha})$ converges to an element of K.

I tried to do the same proof as in the theorem with compact space that includes convergent subnet, but I just feel it`s wrong and something should be different. Can anyone please help me with it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. I can't find the relation between the net and $K$. Could you explain about your question...?

Comment: I`m not sure actually about that. The only thing that I have that both of them are in the same open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\nu=\langle x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\rangle$ be a net in $X$. Recall that $\nu$ is *frequently in* a set $S$ iff for each $\alpha\in I$ there is a $\beta\in I$ such that $\alpha\preceq\beta$ and $x_\beta\in S$. The key step in the problem is the following lemma.

> **Lemma.** Let $x\in X$. If $\nu$ is frequently in every open nbhd of $x$, then $\nu$ has a subnet converging to $x$.
>
> **Proof.** Assume that $\nu$ is frequently in every open nbhd of $x$, and let $\mathscr{N}$ be the family of open nbhds of $X$. For $\langle\alpha,U\rangle,\langle\beta,V\rangle\in I\times\mathscr{N}$ write $\langle\alpha,U\rangle\sqsubseteq\langle\beta,V\rangle$ iff $\alpha\preceq\beta$ and $U\supseteq V$; then $\langle I\times\mathscr{N},\sqsubseteq\rangle$ is a directed set. By hypothesis there is a function $\varphi:I\times\mathscr{N}\to I$ such that $$\alpha\preceq\varphi(\langle\alpha,U\rangle)\quad\text{and}\quad x_{\varphi(\langle\alpha,U\rangle)}\in U$$ for each $\langle\alpha,U\rangle\in I\times\mathscr{N}$. For each $\alpha\in I$ we have $\alpha\preceq\varphi(\langle\beta,U\rangle)$ whenever $\langle\alpha,X\rangle\sqsubseteq\langle\beta,U\rangle$, so $\mu=\langle x_{\varphi(\langle\alpha,U\rangle)}:\langle\alpha,U\rangle\in I\times\mathscr{N}\rangle$ is a subnet of $\nu$. (Here I’m using the definition of subnet in Kelley’s *General Topology*.) Now let $U\in\mathscr{N}$ be arbitrary; there is an $\alpha\in I$ such that $x_\alpha\in U$, and $x_{\varphi(\langle\beta,V\rangle)}\in V\subseteq U$ whenever $\langle\alpha,U\rangle\sqsubseteq\langle\beta,V\rangle$, so $\mu$ converges to $x$. $\dashv$

Now suppose that $K\subseteq X$ is compact, and that if $U$ is any open nbhd of $K$, then $\nu$ is frequently in $U$. Suppose further that no subnet of $\nu$ converges to any point of $K$. Then each $x\in K$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $\nu$ is not frequently in $U_x$. This means that for each $x\in K$ there is an $\alpha(x)\in I$ such that $x_\beta\notin U_x$ whenever $\beta\in I$ and $\alpha(x)\preceq\beta$. $K$ is compact, so there is a finite $F\subseteq K$ such that $K\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in F}U_x$, and $I$ is directed, so there is an $\alpha\in I$ such that $\alpha(x)\preceq\alpha$ for each $x\in F$. But then $\bigcup_{x\in F}U_x$ is an open nbhd of $K$, and $x_\beta\notin U$ whenever $\alpha\preceq\beta$. This contradiction shows that $\nu$ must have a subnet converging to some point of $K$.

Comment: how can I use this result to prove that every compact Hausdorff space is normal? I tried to do it by contradiction by couldn`t really use this result to prove it. Any help?

Comment: @Danny: Normality doesn’t really involve convergence, so I wouldn’t even try to use this result. One of the ideas from the proof, however, does the trick nicely. You need to show that if $X$ is compact, $K\subseteq X$ is closed, and $U$ is an open nbhd of $K$, then there is an open $V$ such that $K\subseteq V\subseteq\operatorname{cl}V\subseteq U$. Assuming that you’ve already proved that a compact Hausdorff space is regular, for each $x\in K$ choose an open $V_x$ such that $x\in V_x\subseteq\operatorname{cl}V_x\subseteq U$, and then use the compactness of $K$ just as I did above.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Just one more thing. Do you have any advice generally to deal with subnets? I have a difficulty dealing with them generally. When I was reading, I was fine with almost all questions except those questions that contains something to prove about subnets. So is there anything that would help me deal with them or understand them more? thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Danny: You’re welcome. What book(s) or other sources have you used so far in reading/learning about nets and subnets?

Comment: introduction to Banach spaces by Robert E. Megginson.

Comment: @Danny: There used to be an outstandingly good PDF on nets and filters by Saitulaa Naranong available online, but it’s no longer where it used to be. I did find it [here](http://www.learningace.com/doc/2930043/2882cc861734107fbecbf02878b1ae16/netsfilters), where you can at least read it, but I don’t immediately see any way to download it. I should mention that in the displayed line in Definition $10.2$ there is a critical typo: the implication is backwards!

Comment: thanks a lot. I`ll read it :)

Comment: @Danny: Good luck! I hope it helps.